# How to give private numbers a recorded message

Tags: samsung

Android lets me block private numbers, but some might be genuine callers trying to get through without realising they are calling from a private number.

How can I set Android (or an app) to give a recorded voice message to private numbers?

The recorded message file can be made using Google text to speech. It would be:

(Male voice) Sorry, the number you have called does not accept calls from private numbers. (Female Voice) Please redial without withholding your number.

Comment: What version of android are you running?